# How to setup and check turpentine varnish cache for Magento?

Tags: magento, caching, varnish

I have setup extension **Turpentine - Varnish cache** on my local server. I have also install varnish on local server by terminal.

In admin panel system->configuration->Turpentine under varnish option and cache there are some options such as **Server List**,**Backend Host**,**Backend Port**, 
I have checked it with my local sever details but it is not working. How can I setup & check it properly? and which credentials should I use for these fields?And also How can I check if cache is generating or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put some inputs like what you got, any error or message etc ..

Comment: I get below error when I add my local IP address 
        Error determining Varnish version: Varnish admin socket timeout
        Failed to apply the VCL to 172.10.1.4:8056: Failed to load configurator
        Error determining Varnish version: Varnish admin socket timeout
        Failed to load configurator

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I have setup the magento and varnish in two different server. In place of 127.0.0.1 I have put the ip in which I setup varnish. I want know that varnish is setup correctly or not. How do I do it ?

Comment: I found that how we can check that Varnish is set up on server properly.

By using terminal : curl -I www.yoursiteurl.com

From third party : http://www.isvarnishworking.com/